# Does having auto_increment ID degrade performance compared to no auto_increment?

Tags: mysql

I have a big table with ID column set as bigint auto_increment. At some time in history we decided to generate IDs on client side as some pseudo-random number.

My question is simple: given that the table column is still set as auto_increment, does this affect performance negatively even though we ALWAYS supply ID in INSERT queries? Is this significant/should I bother to change the schema? The table is EXTREMELY huge and busy, I am afraid I cannot do this without downtime.

Comment: Study [AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html). Do you understand that the only possible answer is "too low facts"?

Comment: Just to clarify, you've started inserting explicit values into an auto-increment column, and you are asking whether there's a significant performance difference between inserting explicit values into an auto-increment column and inserting them into a regular (non-auto-increment) column. Would that be an accurate summary?

Comment: @TomV-TeamMonica we had problems with INSERTing, it was taking too long (this table is extremely busy). So we came with quite a good way to make unique numbers. The algorithm is good, in the very rare occasion conflict occurs we handle it in code.

Comment: @AndriyM Exactly. We started inserting explicit values into an auto-increment column, and need to know whether there's a significant performance difference between inserting explicit values into an auto-increment column and inserting them into a regular (non-auto-increment) column

Comment: @TomV-TeamMonica yeah, I know, but the table likely cant be modified on the fly without downtime. Thats why I am asking

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59392383/does-having-auto-increment-id-degrade-performance-compared-to-no-auto-increment

Comment: Is that auto_inc column the `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: @RickJames yes, that auto_inc is a PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After statically looking at the MySQL (5.7.28) code it makes no difference. Auto_increment locks within innodb [only happen](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/mysql-5.7.28/storage/innobase/row/row0mysql.cc#L1285) if [fetching a new auto_increment value](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/mysql-5.7.28/storage/innobase/handler/ha_innodb.cc#L16722) ([via here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/mysql-5.7.28/storage/innobase/handler/ha_innodb.cc#L7381)), or altering the table to have a different auto_increment value.

Its current dormant status is not causing any impact to you.

Comment: However, it does need to see if the value is already in the table, correct?  And perhaps that uniqueness check is obviated by necessarily grabbing the nex auto_inc id?

Comment: @RickJames: As someone working with SQL Server, I wouldn't expect uniqueness check to be part of auto-increment column implementation. An `IDENTITY` column in SQL Server certainly doesn't work that way, unless you also define the column as unique or PK. I guess auto-inc columns work differently in MySQL. On a different note, when you are inserting an explicit value into an auto-inc column and it's greater than the last auto-generated value, MySQL needs to remember it because it will generate the next value based on it, so I would think that *should* have some, however minimal, impact too.

Comment: @AndriyM - Auto_inc and IDENTITY and Sequence are rather different animals.  MySQL's auto_inc _mostly_ has a _default_ that is one more than the max.  Then there is a lot of careful code to optimize it.  It must be the _first_ column of _some_ index, not necessarily the PK or a UNIQUE key.  MySQL's PK is, by definition, a UNQUE index and is (for InnoDB), clustered with the data.